# Get Magento defined values for model "sales/order" status

Tags: magento, class-method, magento-1.13

I'm trying to perform some operations on an order if its status/state is "processing" (not sure if I should use `status` or `state` here .. any help on this would be great too).

Running a `->getStatus()` on a `sales/order` model tells me the value I'm looking for is "processing", but I don't want to compare this to a string literal. I would like to compare it to the Magento defined value, so I'm wondering how it determines this value "processing" and how can I do the same?

Here is some code..

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderID);
if($order->getStatus() == "processing") {
  //do stuff
}
```

I would like to change `"processing"` to something like `Mage::getModel('sales/order')->STATUS_PROCESSING`

I'm sure the answer lies somewhere in the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::getStatus()` method, but I'm having a very hard time locating that method. I've even used `ReflectionClass` to view the methods and do not see it!

Comment: I don't know exactyl what you are looking for but I did it like this: if ($order->getStatus() === Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING)

Answer (score 0):

The following code will go off of the Magento status code:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', 'Processing')
    ;

foreach ($orders as $order) {
    //do stuff
}
```

I hope that is what you are looking for.